# Could not find artifact org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.5.6 in pom in java

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, artifact

While doing mvn clean package for the project i am getting below error and did not understand the cause of the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project dbimport: Could not resolve dependencies for project 
baag.betl:dbimport:jar:1.13-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.5.6 was cached in the local repository, 
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Below is the part of my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using Intellij for my java project.

Comment: Those are incomplete logs..the complete one would read the source as well in the log you've shared. On the other hand, here is your dependency - https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.5.6/pom

Comment: i have updated my logs bit ...do i need to clear m2 cache or try mvn install ?

Answer (score 11):

From [here.](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.5.6) Have you tried add type as `pom`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: still the issue ...i have updated my logs bit ...do i need to clear m2 cache or try mvn install ?

Comment: The <type>pom</type> fixed it for me